# How to merge rows excluding NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have this dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9C6Y.png)

But I want to merge the two rows so that I have only a single row of just numbers and not the NaN values.

The dataframe was created with one value from a dataframe and then all of the TA values from another dataframe with the concat function. I was hoping concat would put them all in the same row but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0).first()`